# Does updating the Refresh token life Azure AD B2C User flows expire current Refresh tokens

Tags: azure, jwt, azure-ad-b2c

I have a client with mobile apps that uses Azure AD B2C User flows for authentication.

There is a Policy for SignIn that has the Refresh token lifetime (days), this was set too low and we need to increase it.

If we change this policy setting, will it cause currently valid Refresh token's to expire or remain valid?

It is not listed as a reason in [Token revocation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#token-revocation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, change the policy setting won't cause currently valid Refresh token's to expire.

The old refresh token will still be valid.

You can have a quick verification by using [ROPC flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-ropc?tabs=app-reg-ga#test-the-user-flow):

1. Acquire an access token/refresh token pair.
2. Change the **Refresh token lifetime** in ROPC user flow.
3. Use the refresh token above to acquire a new access token.